# How to get custom message for pass expect in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine2.0

I can able to get custom message for failure expect in Jasmine. But i want to get custom message for pass expect also in Jasmine.

I used below code

```
expect(true).toBe(false,'To verify the icon');
```

Custom Message

> Expected true to be false, 'To verify the icon'

But i need custom message for pass expect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add a custom message to the actual `expect`
You will need to wrap it in an it()

```
    it('can verify an icon', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
```